# What is depicted on this piece of artwork?

Tags: catholicism, art, identify-this

Another piece in the belongings of my late grandmother may she rest in peace.

This particular piece is a very beautiful piece in my opinion. This is a part of 7 pieces in total.

I am really intrigued by the artwork itself.

Is it possible for someone to identify this scene?

[image]

Comment: Do you know anything about it? Who made it, where it's from, etc?

Comment: @fredsbend unfortunately no.But i would love to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The picture depicts the **Coronation of the Virgin** or **Coronation of Mary**.

> The Coronation of the Virgin or Coronation of Mary is a subject in Christian art, especially popular in Italy in the 13th to 15th centuries, but continuing in popularity until the 18th century and beyond. Christ, sometimes accompanied by God the Father and the Holy Spirit in the form of a dove, places a crown on the head of Mary as Queen of Heaven. In early versions the setting is a Heaven imagined as an earthly court, staffed by saints and angels; in later versions Heaven is more often seen as in the sky, with the figures seated on clouds. The subject is also notable as one where the whole Christian Trinity is often shown together, sometimes in unusual ways. Although crowned Virgins may be seen in Orthodox Christian icons, the coronation by the deity is not. Mary is sometimes shown, in both Eastern and Western Christian art, **being crowned by one or two angels**, but this is considered a different subject.
>
> The belief in Mary as Queen of Heaven obtained the papal sanction of Pope Pius XII in his encyclical Ad Caeli Reginam (English: Queenship of Mary in Heaven) of October 11, 1954. It is also the fifth Glorious Mystery of the Rosary. The Roman Catholic Church celebrates the feast every August 22, where it replaced the former octave of the Assumption of Mary in 1969, a move made by Pope Paul VI. The feast was formerly celebrated on May 31, at the end of the Marian month, where the present general calendar now commemorates the Feast of the Visitation. In addition, there are Canonical coronations authorized by the Pope which are given to specific Marian images venerated in a particular place. - [Coronation of the Virgin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronation_of_the_Virgin)

The Latin (*Converte nos*)is from Psalm 84 and is part of Complines and  the [Little Office of the Blessed Sacrament](http://www.preces-latinae.org/thesaurus/Euch/OPSSSac.html) amongst other places in the Divine Office of the Church:

> V. Converte nos Deus salutaris noster:
>
> R. Et averte iram tuam a nobis. (Psalm 84:5)

In English:

> V. Convert us, O God our Savior.
>
> R. And turn away Thy wrath from us.

This [illuminated manuscript](https://www.manhattanrarebooks.com/pages/books/1568/illuminated-manuscript/illuminated-manuscript-coronation-of-the-virgin-mary) comes from a beautiful 15th-century leaf from a French Book of Hours with a large miniature of the Coronation of Mary.

> On recto:
>
> Miniature of the Virgin kneeling before the enthroned God the Father, with an angel holding the crown of Mary. Behind them is a canopy. Miniature measures 100 mm x 65 mm (3.9 x 2.6 inches). The image is surrounded by a foliate border with red, blue, and pink flowers with green leaves; border also contains blue and gold acanthus leaves and penwork along left margin. One triple-line illuminated initial (the letter “C”) in burnished gold and red with white details. One single-line initial in burnished gold and blue. The text, in gold-brown Latin gothic script, is from Psalm 84:5.
>
> On verso:
>
> 20 lines of text in gold-brown Latin gothic script on vellum. One double-line illuminated initial in burnished gold and blue with white details. 11 single-line illuminated initials in burnished gold and red/blue with white details. The text is from Psalm 69:2 and Psalm 128.

I do not know if you have the reverse side of this image, so I will include it as part of my answer.

[image: Illuminated Manuscript: Coronation of the Virgin Mary]

[Illuminated Manuscript: Coronation of the Virgin Mary](https://www.manhattanrarebooks.com/pages/books/1568/illuminated-manuscript/illuminated-manuscript-coronation-of-the-virgin-mary)

Answer (score 3):

Again, this priceless artwork was made by a holy artist and the scene is a continuation of Mary's title. Notice how the artist change the background compared to the other post to make it into *"A Beautiful Heavenly Realm"* what a genius stroke.I think your seven pieces of artworks depicts the Titles of Mary based on Church Tradition and Church Fathers teaching. But, this one had a link to the Assumption Dogma and Mary was crown as Sovereign Queen of Heaven and Earth.

> The title of this painting is ***"The Coronation of the Blessed Virgin Mary as Queen of Heaven and Earth".***. It is the fifth Glorious Mystery of the Holy Rosary.

I assume if you have seven collection of this artwork, the other five pertains to other mysteries of the Holy Rosary. I'm curious how the artist depicted the *"Assumption of Mary into Heaven"* or the *"Annunciation"* if it happened that it is included in one of the seven artwork.

***Explanation of the priceless artwork:***

1. *The artwork shown the Glorified Jesus seated on the Throne wearing a royal robe inside depicting the same color of Mary's garment as King of Heaven & Earth. Jesus King of Kings and Lord of Lords was clothe with Light of Holiness. And from the image the source of Holiness is the Cross depicted by the right hand of Jesus on top of source of Holiness. The halo of the Blessed Virgin Mary and the Saints emanates from the Cross of Christ meaning those who follow gospel command to lift up their crosses and follow Jesus Way of the Cross will be crown in Heavenly glories.We can also say Jesus being the High Priest also wear the white priestly garments similar to the Pope.*

As St.Paul said;

> "I have fought the good fight, I have finished the race, I have kept the faith. From now on the ***crown of righteousness*** is laid up for me, which the Lord, the righteous judge, will award to me on that day— and not only to me, but to all who crave His appearing. "(2 Timothy4:7-8)

2. *Mary Assumptions is also depicted here by the artist if we look upon the Her Clothe at Pentecost it was the same meaning Mary was assumed into Heaven "body & soul".Blessed Virgin Mary received Her crown from the Hand of Jesus kneeling depicting Her profound humility. Noticed the face of Jesus, Mary and the angles are glowing white unlike the previous painting which only showed Mary & John are two who possessed it. The angels were rejoicing blowing the trumpet and playing the harp. The Almighty God, the Most Holy Trinity was represented by the rays of Light on top like a dome showing Almighty God is the source of power that emantes from Jesus & Mary Kingship & Queenship.*

Below is a description how Mary was crown in Heaven although the Most Holy Trinity in the artwork is only represented here as the source of Light.

I found the back cover translator's notes of the small book compiled by a deceased Bosconian Priest Fr.Adolf Faroni, SDB fascinating. The title of the book taken from St.Bonaventure words ***"Mary, the jewel of the human race",*** it composes of words of praises and quotes coming from 99 famous Saints & Church Fathers and Popes.Also, it contains a beautiful prayer to Mary coming from St.John Paul II the Great whose known for the famous line "Totus Tuus" composed during the Celebration of the Marian Year.

Below is the back cover tranlator's notes describing the **"Salve Regina"**

> *"Then the Eternal Father announced to all the angels & saints; "Our Daughter Mary has been chosen by our will from among all creatures as the first in our favor, and she has never fallen from the position of a true Daughter.Therefore, She has a claimed to our Kingdom, of which She is to be acknowledged and crowned the lawful Sovereign and Queen"*.
>
> *The Incarnate Word declared; "To my true and natural Mother belong all the creatures that I have created and redeemed.And of all things over which I am King, She too shall be the rightful Queen." And the Holy Ghost said; "By the title of my only chosen Spouse, to which She has faithfully corresponded, the crown of Queen is also due to Her for all eternity." Then the three Divine Persons solemnly placed on Mary's bowed head a splendid gleaming crown of glory which far exceeds in beauty any crown that ever has been or ever will be rewarded to a creature by God. At the same time a Voice sounded from the Throne saying; "Our Beloved and Chosen One among creatures, Our Kingdom is yours.You are the Queen and Sovereign of the Seraphim and of all our ministering angels and of all the created universe.We give you power,majesty and dominion over it. While filled with grace beyond all others, you humbled yourself to the lowest place in your own estimation. Receive now the Supreme Honor which you deserve, and participate in the Sovereign Power exercised by the Divinity over all that Our Omnipotence has created. From your Royal Throne you shall rule over hell and earth and nature. Our own Will shall ever be ready to accomplish your will.*
>
> Book : **"Mary the Jewel of human race"** (*compiled by Fr.Adolf Faroni, SDB*)
>
> *Nihil Obstat*: **Daniel V. Flynn, J.C.C Censor Liborium**
>
> *Imprimatur*: **Patrick J. Sheridan, D.D. vicar General**, Archdiocese of New York

i'm looking forward to other five remaining priceless piece of artwork. The artist for me is holy and was guided by the Holy Spirit in expressing the Titles and Praises that belongs to Mary as scriptures ***"all generation shall call me blessed."***

**Others:**
The latin phrase takes this essence of prayer.

> ***V. Converte nos, Deus salutaris noster.
>   R. Et averte iram tuam a nobis.***
>
> ***V. Convert us, O God our Savior.
>   R. And turn away Thy wrath from us.***

[Parvum Officium Sanctissimi Sacramenti](http://www.preces-latinae.org/thesaurus/Euch/OPSSSac.html)